# Printing columns from dataframe with column names that have a similar string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns whose names end with `_avg`. Sometimes I want to do some quick analysis and just print all those columns ending with `_avg`.

Is there something like

```
print(df["*_avg"])
```

where `*` is used like how it's used in shell?

Comment: You can use `df.filter(like="_avg")` or `df.filter(regex=".*_avg")`.

Comment: Search by a string wildcard: `df.loc[:,[True if re.search('*_avg',column) else False for column in df.columns]] `